# Limit number of '1' in a string using Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am trying to make a Regexp to match a expression which has more or equal to two `'1'`s.
Here is what I have written till now -

```
puts "Match." if /(1){1,5}/ =~ test_string
```

This correctly matches strings having `'1'` more than or equal to two, but it still matches if the numbers of occurrences of `'1'` is greater than 5.

How can I correct this Regexp to only match strings having 1 to 5 occurrences of `1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are possibly better versions, but this seems to do the trick:

```
  /^([^1]*1){1,5}[^1]*$/
```

Broken down:

- `^` - Start of string
- `[^1]*1` - Zero or more non-1 characters
- `1` - A '1'.
- `([^1]*1){1,5}` - This pattern occurring between one and five times.
- `[^1]*` - Zero or more non-1 characters
- `$` - End of string

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark your answer as correct in about 8 minutes.

Comment: Actually `^` and `$` matches the start and the end of the line respectively. To match the start and the end of the string you should use `\A` and `\z`, see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Anchors).

Comment: @toro2k I assumed line == string in this case, but you are correct, yes.

Answer (score 3):

***@Adrian Wragg*** already have explained the answer,as asked by OP.But I would like to propose another possible solution for this problem,which is below:

```
puts "Match." if "#{test_string}".count("1") >= 2
```

Comment: He asked to use Regex. This isn't regex.

Comment: @screenmutt Yes..I know that..But non-reg solution is very easy in this case..to show that I put it here..For this case `String#count` is fare enough.

Comment: @screenmutt Sometimes there are better approaches than the one envisioned by the asker. These should be encouraged. Babai, it would be ideal if you first answer the question as asked and *then* propose the alternate solution.

Comment: @MarkThomas You are right..but the Regex already has been answered before me follow this post..So I started like that *You could do also*.. :)

Comment: @Babai, that's better, you're almost there. :) To make it completely self-contained, I'd put an actual regex-based solution in your answer, give it proper attribution (like you did), then propose your alternate.

Comment: @Babai If it helps, I often work on the basis that the question is a very simplified version of the task that an OP is trying to solve, so he may have a need for a RegExp that isn't part of the scope of the question. OTOH, Joe Bloggs coming across this question from a Google search would likely benefit from finding out your alternative. Therefore, I fully support your answering of this question with a simpler alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have strings which contain characters other than one, here is a Regex that will do the job. See an example [here at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/wCwiZMVpqW).

```
/\A([^1]*1[^1]*){1,5}\Z/
```

This will match any strings with 2 or more ones. See an example [here at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/an15th4WRW).

```
/\A1{2,}\Z/
```

This will match any string with 1-5 ones. See an example [here at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/2h6XDuTmw0).

```
/\A1{1,5}\Z/
```